# IIS Express self-signed certificate not trusted

Tags: asp.net, ssl, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

When debugging a new .net core website (file => new project) in Visual Studio 2017, I am prompted with the question if I wish to trust the self-signed IIS express certificate:

[image]

However, after clicking "Yes", I don't get the security warning to add the certificate. Instead, I am redirected to the browser directly, and get a security warning:

[image]

I am running Windows 10

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Edit:

According to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-and-web-tools-20132-preview-for-visual-studio-2013-release-notes#ssl), I should get a security warning after clicking "Yes". But that window is not shown. (I know, that guide is about VS2013).

Comment: Can you provide a translation in English for that error message? Most browsers can allow you to bypass the certificate error. (ex: [Chrome](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-bypass-your-connection-is-not-private-message))

Comment: Ok, I edited my post. I simply did not notice it was in my language.

Comment: @Nasreddine I know I can click "Advanced" and then "Proceed" (as I am doing it now). However, in the long run, I really wish I could trust the IIS Express self-signed certificate.

Comment: I restarted Edge and then it worked (no security warning).

Answer (score 13):

Try the following on your command prompt:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

Comment: The only other solution I had found was to uninstall Visual Studio and IIS Express which I didn't consider an option...This solution just saved my day

Comment: I had to restart Visual Studio and/or my browser (Edge) to get this to take effect. Not sure which of these were required as both were restarted, but this solution worked fine after the restarts.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.lextudio.com/why-chrome-says-iis-express-https-is-not-secure-and-how-to-resolve-that-d906a183f0?source=linkShare-509776cef47e-1509798792

You are not installing the latest IIS Express, and the certificate is not trusted by Chrome.

Either you create another certificate as I hinted in the blog post or you install latest Visual Studio 2017 with IIS Express.